# _ViewStart.cshtml is not able to find view inside area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created area named "Admin", inside it I have shared folder having `_Layout.cshtml`. I also have `_ViewStart.cshtml` inside "Admin" area which makes `_Layout.cshtml` as default view.

When I run page inside Admin area it is giving me error

```
The layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" could not be found at the following path: 
  "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
```

If I put Shared folder in root view, it is working fine, but it is not working inside area.

I hope you understand my problem. Needed Help.